# How can i do a for each row loop inside a for each row loop in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Well guys I'm trying to do a for each row loop inside another for each row loop, i'm really new to mysql and this is my frist trigger I have a table named Disponivel and what I wanted was to see if each of the rows which I'm trying to insert on the table named Venda is already in the table Disponivel and if that's the case I want to insert it into the table Venda. If the row which I'm trying to insert is not part of the table Disponivel then it shall not be insert into the table Venda. Can anyone help? This is what I have.

```
  DELIMITER $$
    create trigger venda_disponivel
        before insert on Venda
    for each row begin
        for each row in Disponivel begin
            if ((new.nomeA = Disponivel.nomeA) and (new.dia = Disponivel.dia) and (new.mes = Disponivel.mes) and (new.ano = Disponivel.ano) and (new.nomeR = Disponivel.nomeR)) then
            end if;
        end;
    end$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

It's giving me this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'for each row in Disponivel begin      if ((new.nomeA
>   = Disponivel.nomeA) and (new.d' at line 4

```
create table Disponivel(
    NomeA       varchar(80),
    NomeR       varchar(80),
    dia     integer,
    mes     varchar(45),
    ano     integer,
    primary key(nomeA, nomeR, dia, mes, ano),
    foreign key(nomeA) references Prato(nomeA),
    foreign key(nomeR) references Restaurante(nomeR),
    foreign key(dia, mes, ano) references Data(dia, mes, ano));

create table Venda(
    NomeA       varchar(80),
    dia     integer,
    mes     varchar(45),
    ano     integer,
    nomeR       varchar(80),
    num         integer,
    primary key(nomeA, nomeR, dia, mes, ano),
    foreign key(nomeA) references Prato(nomeA),
    foreign key(nomeR) references Restaurante(nomeR),
    foreign key(dia, mes, ano) references Data(dia, mes, ano));
```

Comment: Please post exact table schemas for `Venda` and `Disponivel` in a form of `CREATE TABLE ...` statements

Comment: done, is that what u meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR EACH` **is not a looping construct** in MySQL. `FOR EACH ROW` is merely a clause that is part of [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) statement and just denotes the fact that code that goes after will be executed for each row being affected by a trigger.

Now can enforce this constraint without a trigger through an additional FK

```
create table Venda(
    NomeA       varchar(80),
    dia     integer,
    mes     varchar(45),
    ano     integer,
    nomeR       varchar(80),
    num         integer,
    primary key(nomeA, nomeR, dia, mes, ano)
    ,foreign key(nomeA) references Prato(nomeA)
    ,foreign key(nomeR) references Restaurante(nomeR)
    ,foreign key(dia, mes, ano) references Data(dia, mes, ano)
    ,foreign key(nomeA, nomeR, dia, mes, ano) references Disponivel(nomeA, nomeR, dia, mes, ano)
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a170/1)** demo. Try to uncomment the last insert and click `Build Schema`. You'll see that the FK won't let to insert this row.

Comment: posted  the schemas (:

Comment: thanks man it's working! ;) and here i was thinking about using triggers